# ST600 recording issues - files created but no sounds

Tags: soundtrap

We just got two st600s back from the field and the data is really really quiet - it appeared to have recorded but it's almost as if the hydrophone wasn't connected and it's just fuzz. These were brand new last year and tested and gain was set to high during the programming. Has anyone come up against this before? Super irritating.

Answer (score 1):

The only suggestion at this point is to re-test the system:

- Off-load your 'recordings'; one never knows.
- prepare a new recording (make screenshot of deploy control) for some short time
- touch gently  the hydrophone and whistle very close
- stop recording
- offload data and    check data

While checking the deploy control form, I'm not sure what happens if

- periodic recording is not checked and filled-in
- sample rate is disabled (by mistake)

In case you did keep a screeen-shot of your deploy control form (which is always a good idea) you may check the settings.

Also, inspecting the xml log file would tell you when the ST did what